# Adding element to jQuery Mobile using Javascript function

Tags: javascript, list, jquery-mobile

I am adding element to jquery mobile site. While I use exact same function the list classes are different when loading right when building the page and adding using a Javascript function.
The first row is created when applying the following code during loading the page. The second row is created after calling  SignFunc() function where the output is populateRecent("added from a JS function").

```
function populateRecent(x) {
     var x ='<ul  data-role="listview" data-input="#myFilter" data-inset="true"><li id="contact1"><a href="#">'+x+'</a></li></ul>';
     $("#myList").append(x);
}
  SignFunc();
  populateRecent("added when building the page");
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You just need to tell jQM to enhance or refresh the widget. In your example, you are adding a whole new listview to a container each time you call populateRecent(). Therefore you can just tell the container to enhance its contents:

```
$("#myList").append(x).enhanceWithin();
```

If you are really intending to add listitems to an existing listview, you can tell the listview to refresh:

```
var x ='<li id="contact1"><a href="#">'+x+'</a></li>';
$("#myListUL").append(x).listview("refresh");
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8q768n5p/)**

In the demo, click the top button to add new items...

Comment: Thanks mate. I also had to remove this to work, not sure how ajax effects the whole thing   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>